# How can I solve Python's "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, tuples, openpyxl

I am experimenting with **openpyxl**.
I am trying to print a block of data from an excel sheet.
Here is my code:

```
1. from openpyxl import load_workbook
2. 
3. wk = load_workbook(filename='Copy of Reviewed formulasi 2020R1.xlsx')  #wk stands for workbook
4. 
5. s = wk.active  #s stands for sheet
6. 
7. print(s["B5":"M4"].value)
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Asus/PycharmProjects/Reviewed Formulasi/venv/Excel Link.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(s["B5":"M4"].value)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Is there any way that I can actually print blocks from excel?

Comment: We cannot reproduce your problem, because we have no access to your files. So solemnly based on the error, I would say print `s["B5":"M4"]`, which will be a `tuple`, in any case `(item1, item2)`, instead of your expected `item1` with the attribute `value`. Please take a look at the [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), in case your problem isn't solved.

Comment: A block does not have a value. It's a collection of cells, each with its *own* value.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing this way:

```
cell = s['B5': 'D6']
for c1, c2, c3 in cell:
    print("{0:30} {1:30} {2:30}".format(c1.value, c2.value, c3.value))
```

Format is only used so that the output is displayed properly while printing.

Simply printing -> print(c1.value, c2.value, c3.value) will also work.